# What software is being used to develop android apps for profit?

Tags: android

What software is being used successfully to develop android apps and not get caught up in rights nightmares? I want to be able to sell/distribute freely.
Any input would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This question is too general and would most likely cause arguing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the developer documents here: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

If you code the app all yourself you will not have any issues.

Comment: So the code the developer tools generate would have to be done from scratch by me?

Comment: Yes all the code you write would have to be done by you.

Comment: Creating a text field in eclipse will "auto generate" the basic code to work with. Based on your answer I would need to re-type it all?

Comment: No, anything you that is made with eclipse is all yours. As long as you don't someone's code.